# Hooking functions located in the executable (not in shared libraries)

Tags: c, hook, elf, dlsym

Let's say I have a function `foo` in `./elf`.
I want to hook it with `foo_hook` which is located in my shared object.
`foo` is not exported from `./elf`.

`LD_PRELOAD` is useful for hooking functions in shared objects, but is there a **generic** way to hook functions in the executable?
I consider injecting with ptrace not very generic.

Also, `foo_hook` doesn't have to be in a shared object, if there is some other simple way (instead of writing shellcode) it is acceptable.

I prefer not to patch `./elf`, but that is not a necessity. Changing the dynamic linker/RPATH is also ok.
Rebuilding `./elf` is not possible.

Comment: It's unclear from your question whether you can rebuild the executable or not, and whether `foo` is exported from it (appears in `nm -D elf` output).

Comment: You can arrange the order of lib in the link command if you want to do it during build. You can also change LD_LIBRARY_PATH to add path to your directory.

Comment: @EmployedRussian Added missing information

Answer (score 2):

> is there a generic way to hook functions in the executable?

No.

Comment: Rewrite the source and recompile it.  ;-)